# Kotlinx Serialization for a generic sealed class (like an api result)

Tags: serialization, ktor

her is my sealed class

```
@Serializable
sealed class ApiResponse {
    @Serializable
    @SerialName("ApiResponse.Success")
    data class Success<out T : Any>(val value: T) : ApiResponse()

    @Serializable
    @SerialName("ApiResponse.Failure")
    object Failure : ApiResponse()

    @Serializable
    @SerialName("ApiResponse.InFlight")
    object InFlight : ApiResponse()
}
```

I am getting this error when I call it

> Can't locate argument-less serializer for class Success. For generic
> classes, such as lists, please provide serializer explicitly.

I know I am missing something.  Is there an easy way to serialize this?  Also what is the value of inflight (saw this in an example, but I see tremendous value - I am using ktor for client and server)

Comment: Can you elaborate your client configuration and what serializtion library do you use?